# Why 'os.system' output is 0 when I try to convert it to a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system

why the output is 0 when I try to convert int to a string?
I'm searching how to fix it, but can't find it.

**here is my code :**

```py
import os
value = "cat /home/username/project/value.txt"
print("the value is : " + str(os.system(value)))
```

**the output is :**

```py
726
the value is : 0
```

**i want to make it like this :**

```py
the value is : 726
```

Comment: `os.system()` returns the _exit code_ of the process, not its _output_.

Comment: If you want to collect _output_, `os.system()` is the wrong tool for the job. Use the `subprocess` module instead.